# MVC 4 datetime validation failure when attempting to edit only the time

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

From a Database first approach, I am trying to edit only the time within a DateTime field, generated from a table that I cannot change (so changing it from SQL's datetime to something else is out of the question).  The problem I am having is the validator keeps telling me that what is in the box is not a valid date unless I also include the date.

Here is what I have so far:

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Time")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:h:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime PrintTime { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrintTime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrintTime)
    </div>
```

I have tried a ModelBinder, and I have tried using a custom validation attribute (both of which compile successfully and were taken from here), but no matter what I do, even with those solutions, the error I get on validation is:

"The field Time must be a date"

I have seen other threads indicating the possibility of jquery having a date requirement that I can't get past (as far as the threads have suggested for solutions) and it seems the solutions there are to disable validation entirely.  Obviously, I'd like to keep validation (it works fine for everything else).

So what can I do to fix this?

Comment: I would recommend using HiddenFor for PrintTime and add Html.Editor for the time only.  Set the time on the post back.

Comment: Thank you, atbebtg.  I did exactly that and will answer my own question below with the workaround solution I used (in case anyone else wants an answer to this).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a workaround.  First, I added a string to the model that is not in the database, then added some methods to the model.  This will cause problems if you refresh the model from the database, so be careful!

Here is what was added to the model:

```
    [DisplayName("Daily Print Time")]
    [RegularExpression("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9][\\s]*[apAP][mM][\\s]*", ErrorMessage="Invalid Time Format")]
    [Required]
    public string sPrintTime { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Daily Print Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:h:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public System.DateTime PrintTime { get; set; }
```

Methods:

```
    public void UpdatePrintTime()
    {
        //This is a workaround to get past jquery validation errors when
        //attempting to edit a DateTime value directly with just a time string.
        DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime.TryParse("12/30/1899 " + sPrintTime.ToUpper(), out dt);
        if (dt != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            PrintTime = dt;
        }
    }
    public void UpdatePrintString()
    {
        sPrintTime = PrintTime.ToString("h:mm tt");
    }
```

The Regular Expression validation is not perfect (for example, it will still let you enter "23:59 am", but the Method UpdatePrintTime() takes care of that with TryParse().

Next, I updated the Edit.cshtml file like so:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PrintTime)
```

The above line needed to be added in order to avoid runtime errors due to a missing field

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sPrintTime)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sPrintTime)
</div>
```

I also had to update the Create.cshtml file with the above <div>.  Note: I did not include the hidden PrintTime field because of the Methods I added, which I use in the Controller actions Edit and Create like so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PrintJob printjob)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            printjob.UpdatePrintTime();
            db.PrintJobs.Add(printjob);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ...
        return View(printjob);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        PrintJob printjob = db.PrintJobs.Find(id);
        if (printjob == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        printjob.UpdatePrintString();
        ...
        return View(printjob);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(PrintJob printjob)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            printjob.UpdatePrintTime();
            db.Entry(printjob).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        printjob.UpdatePrintString();
        ...
        return View(printjob);
    }
```

ALL of this was needed to get it to work.  Now it will give me a different validation error when I try to enter in something wrong, and double checks what was entered even if it passes validation.  If it passes client side validation, but not TryParse(), then it will leave the time exactly as it was, if in edit mode.  If in create mode, it throws an exception.

So the two flaws are 1) the validation doesn't match up with TryParse(), and therefore 2) can let slip a bad time string which will cause an exception.

Other than that, this is the solution I came up with, in full. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm having the same problem. I think this workaround will solve my problem.